# Using Arangodb to implement a queue

Tags: arangodb

Is there a way to implement a thread-safe concurrent queue store using arangodb?
I read this article from RocksDB that using a KV store, a scalable persistent queue service can be implemented "easily", does this apply to ArangoDB as well? I read somewhere that Arango uses RocksDB as storage engine for it's KV store, so I was wondering if someone has already tried this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, but for whatever reason (probably bone-headed implementation) I ran into resource contention issues (deadlock), even at low usage rates.

ArangoDB does indeed use RocksDB as the default storage engine (MMFiles is deprecated) but doesn't expose RocksDB internals other than a few knobs to tweak for performance tuning.  If you want something *VERY* similar to the RocksDB-based solution, ArangoDB is probably not what you are looking for, but ArangoDB does provide a sort of K/V solution.

Since ArangoDB only supports two "collection" types ("document" and "edge"), a K/V-store is really an implementation method, not an option you choose.  [Their idea](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/architecture-deployment-modes-cluster-data-models.html#keyvalue-pairs) is to use the native "_key" attribute (present in every document, unique, automatically indexed) with a single "value" attribute, creating a document like:

```json
{
   "_key": "my awesome key name",
   "value": "supercool"
}
```

Part of my use-case was to create a queue of "nonce" tokens that I would pick-up when a request came in, to act as a sort of cheap resource governor.  However, the queue quickly became overwhelmed when I tried to go with sub-1-second query rates, giving me deadlocks when it tried to access/lock tokens that were being written.

Again, I believe this could have been sorted out, but the project went in a different direction and I never ended up troubleshooting it to completion.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Transactions](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/transactions.html), for more details check how ArangoDB implements [Foxx queues](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/foxx-reference-modules-queues.html), [foxx/queues code @ github](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/tree/devel/js/server/modules/@arangodb/foxx/queues)